# Using save twice with F expression

Tags: python, django

When executing the following code.

```
from django.db.models import F

# assume that stories_filed is 0 at the start. 
reporter = Reporters.objects.get(name='Tintin')
reporter.stories_filed = F('stories_filed') + 1
reporter.save()
reporter.save()
```

The result is that `stories_filed` is equal to `2`. Why is that, and is there a good way of avoiding this mistake. Would wrapping it in a transaction prevent the issue?

Comment: Does not seem to work wrapping it in a transaction.

Comment: `reporter.stories_filed += 1` ?

Comment: `F('stories_filed')` means that you will update it with `UPDATE table_name SET stories_filed = stories_filed + 1`

Comment: Seeing in the docs;  "If it’s initially 1, the final value will be 3. This persistence can be avoided by reloading the model object after saving it, for example, by using refresh_from_db()." But using refresh_from_db makes you do another query, which isn't exactly desirable. I guess I'll just have to be very careful about executing save() when using f expressions...

Comment: @Jonathan: well often `.save()` is not called multiple times. Using `F` objects is performed to avoid race conditions, since now the database is responsible for the concurrent updates.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yup, which is why I was using `F` objects in the first place. I wasn't fully aware of the side effect that calling save twice would increment it again. Thus if you've got a sneaky save in the wrong place you could end up with a somewhat nasty bug.

Comment: @Jonathan: you do not need per se to use `F` expressions in an *object*, you can also work with the ORM, and thus specify `Reporters.objects.filter(name='Tintin').update(stories_filed=F('stories_filed')+1)`. Of course calling this twice will have the same effect, but it is less likely than calling `.save()` on an object, since these can be hidden in a `ModelForm`, etc. whereas such ORM calls, are more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [**`F`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) is a *reference* to a field. If you set `stories_filed` to `F('stories_filed') + 1`, then when you `.save()`, it will make a query that looks like:

```
UPDATE app_reporter
SET stories_filed = stories_filed + 1
WHERE pk = pk-of-object
```

It will thus increment the field at the *database* side. Indeed, if you query what `reporter.stories_filed` is, it will specify that this is `F('stories_filed') + 1`, so the increment logic is *not* performed at the Django/Python level.

Note that if you `.save()` an object, the object is *not* reloaded from the database, so *after* the first `.save()`, the `stories_filed` is still `F('stories_filed') + 1`, so a second `.save()` call, will query another increment.

It is however recommended to do this with an `F` object, since there are *race conditions* where multiple views update the same record, it could mean that certain increments are lost. Indeed, if two views would both work with:

```
reporter = Reporters.objects.get(name='Tintin')
reporter.stories_filed += 1
reporter.save()
```

Then it is possible that *after* both views end, the value is only incremented once, that is because both first load the same record, they both increment it with one, and then they both save the new value, but the second view will thus save the record with `stories_filed` being incremented from the record it retrieved, and not taking the update of the other view into account.